# Error in using same card for subscription and one off payment

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Scenario:
I want to create a subscription and also one time payment with the same card. I am using 3D secure card number 4000002500003155 so I got a popup to convert 3D autentication. Once I confirm, I submit payment method to server using Ajax, and I update the default payment method and subscription is creating successfully but one time charge with the same  default payment method is throwing this exception:
"The payment attempt failed because additional action is required before it can be completed."

How can I use the same card to create subscription and one off payment with 3D secure card: 4000002500003155

Here is my frontend code:

```
stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret, {
payment_method: {
  card: cardElement,
  billing_details:{ name: "{{$data->first_name}} {{$data->last_name}}"}
  },}).then(function(result) {
if(result.error){
}else{
}}
```

Hoping for some help in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you review the [description for that test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards), you'll see that it requires 3DS for one time payments unless set up and used as off-session.

If you make your one-time payment intent  as [off-session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php#create_payment_intent-off_session), after doing the card setup and attaching to a customer as you've done, then it should succeed.

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'customer' => 'cus_123',
  'payment_method' => 'pm_456',
  'off_session' => true,
  'confirm' => true,
]);
```